# How to Use Multi WHERE and ORDER BY

Tags: php, database

I'm assembling a search box on my blog. For default, the script like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topics WHERE message LIKE '%" . $description . "%' ORDER BY message LIMIT 10";
```

This script will only search data from the message row. I want to add another row. Eg `title`.

I modified the script like this in the hope keyword will trace message row and title:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topics WHERE message, title LIKE '%" . $description . "%' ORDER BY message, title LIMIT 10";
```

Turns out it did not work. How should?

Comment: You can use 2 conditions: `WHERE message LIKE '%...%' OR title LIKE '%...%'`

Comment: Use a `FULLTEXT` index with `MATCH` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Why are people down voting this question?  Something I'm missing?

Comment: Do not know me, maybe because they're too clever with a problem like this. But your answer really helped me. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for

```
"SELECT id, title FROM topics WHERE message LIKE '%" . $description . "%' or title LIKE '%" . $description . "%' ORDER BY message, title LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This query...

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topics WHERE message LIKE '%$description%' OR title LIKE '%$description%' ORDER BY message, title LIMIT 10";
```